# How can I get long dictation results from the REST Speech Recognition API from Microsofts Cognitive Services?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I was able to get short dictation answers from the REST API of Bing Voice Recognition. My goal is to get responses for audio-files that are longer than 15-30 seconds (aka long dictation mode). So what I do for getting the short answers is the following (I'm developing a HTML uwp app):

1. Generate an `ArrayBuffer` from an audio file (wav)
2. Authentication through Access Token
3. Send Audio data to REST API with the following settings:

```js
var accessToken = [[accessTocken]];
var url = 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?'; 
var params = {
    'version': '3.0',
    'format': 'json',
    'locale': 'en-US',
    'device.os': 'Windows OS',
    'scenarios': 'smd',
    'appid': 'D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5',
    'requestid': guid(),
    'instanceid': guid()
};
var options = {
    url: url + $.param(params),
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'audio/wav; samplerate=16000'
    },
    data: data
};
return WinJS.xhr(options);
```

So this works! But how can I do this for long dictation scenarios?

Please don't reference the JavaScript GitHub repository at https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Javascript. This works only for short dictation AND is not working in the Edge browser.

Answer (score 1):

From API documentation:

> Your application must endpoint the audio to determine start and end of
>   speech, which in turn is used by the service to determine the start
>   and end of the request. You may not upload more than 10 seconds of
>   audio in any one request and the total request duration cannot exceed
>   14 seconds.

Ref:
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition

Maybe you need to implement the Client Library to use the differents modes.

> ShortPhrase mode: an utterance up to 15 seconds long. As data is sent
>   to the server, the client will receive multiple partial results and
>   one final multiple N-best choice result.
>
> LongDictation mode: an utterance up to 2 minutes long. As data is sent
>   to the server, the client will receive multiple partial results and
>   multiple final results, based on where the server indicates sentence
>   pauses.
>
> Intent detection: The server returns additional structured information
>   about the speech input. To use Intent you will need to first train a
>   model. See details here.

Ref:
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStartedCSharpDesktop